# System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter error when trying to consume web service from vbscript

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, vbscript

I have the code below to consume a web service using javascript. The code works well when I invoke a Dummy method that has no parameters and just returns a string, but when I attempt to invoke a method that has a single parameter, `XmlNode` in this case, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: XmlNode.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

VBScript function:

```vb
Function ConsumeWebService(SamplePlan)
    Dim oXML_Aux

    Dim strURL
    Dim logger:Set logger = New EMR_Logging
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
    Dim strEnvelope

    logger.LogInfo "Invoking ConsumeWebService - StartTime: " &  Now
    Set oXML_Aux = CreateObject(DOMDocument)
    strEnvelope = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:tem=""http://tempuri.org/"">" _
       & " <soap:Header/>" _
       & " <soap:Body>" _
       & "   <tem:SyncSamplePlan_DCA>" _
       & "       <tem:XmlNode><![CDATA[" & SamplePlan & "]]></tem:XmlNode>" _
       & "    </tem:SyncSamplePlan_DCA>" _
       & " </soap:Body>" _
       & " </soap:Envelope>"

    Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    oXMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = GetRef("HandleStateChange")

    strURL = "http://ocn-da2.lsecmes.rvoaustin.local/GNE_OCN_Webparts/QC_Sampling_Plan_Import/QC_Sample_Plan_Import.asmx/SyncSamplePlan_DCA"
    call oXMLHTTP.open("POST", strURL, False)

    call oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded") 'orig
    oXML_Aux.loadXml strEnvelope

    call oXMLHTTP.send(oXML_Aux.xml)
    logger.LogInfo "Invoking Web Service- strSoapEnvelope: " & strEnvelope
End Function

Sub HandleStateChange
    if(oXMLHTTP.readyState = 4) then
        dim szResponse: szResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText

       call oXMLDoc.loadXML(szResponse)

       if (oXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
           call msgbox(oXMLDoc.parseError.reason)
       else
           call msgbox(oXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("string")(0).childNodes(0).text)
       end if
   end If
End Sub
```

So basically my question is what I'm doing wrong? If you check the line where I populate the `strEnvelope` variable, I'm explicitly populating the `XmlNode` parameter. I took the Soap envelope for this web service method using Soap UI, and if go to the logs (you can see that I'm logging the `strEnvelope` variable value at the end of the first function), and get the value from this `strEnvelope` variable and put it in Soap UI, it works with no issues, so with this I can confirm that the Soap envelope I'm using for this method is ok. I suspect the issue might be related with the `SetRequestHeader` property I'm using, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help me here?

Note: I'm executing the vbscript within the same server that hosts the web service.
This is the response I get logged in Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 17 Sep 2014 21:48:23 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 404

System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: XmlNode.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it.
The web service was always working if I invoked it from IE (when you open IIS, right click on the web service `.asmx` file, and click on browse), so I looked at the call in Fiddler and found out that the SOAP envelope that worked only had:
`XmlNode=<samples><sample>`

instead of having the entire SOAP envelope I was using in my original post. So I found that when you see the service definition (when you open IIS, right click on the web service `.asmx` file, and click on browse), there are three examples, `soap1.1`, `soap1.2` and `HTTP Post`, so in this scenario I had to use the `HTTP Post` example. So this is how the code looks now:

So this is how I populate the Envelope now:

```vb
Dim strEnvelope:strEnvelope = "XmlNode=" & SamplePlan
```